# Integral of gamma - exponential product

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

The following integral is part of a calculation I have been working on:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ibx}x^{-a}\Gamma(a,ix)dx
$$

where a is a strictly natural number and $b=1/4$, $i$ is the imaginary unit and $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function. Integration by parts is not helpful, since the argument will appear again in the process, no matter which combination between the three terms we choose. I have been stuck on this for quite a while, any advice is welcome!

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I updated the initial question, thank you.

Comment: Why do you introduce $b$ if it is just $1/4$?

Comment: @Gary, it was a typo, fixed.

Comment: The integrand behaves like $x^{-a}$ near $x=0$. How do you integrate over it when $a>0$?

Comment: @Gary, then in reaching this step of the calculation I must have made some assumption I wasn't supposed to. Thank you for pointing this out! I'll accept the answer below, as my description was not clear enough in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a<1$, Mathematica gives for
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ibx}\,x^{-a}\,\Gamma(a,ix)\,dx$$
$$I=e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  a}\, b^{a-1} \,\sin (\pi  a)
   \left(B_{b^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{2},0\right)+B_{b^2}\left(1-\frac{a}{2
   },0\right)\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that a>1 and b=1/4.